# Lightbox with a custom layout

Tags: html, css

My goal is to achieve a lightbox like shown in this picture :

[image]

> Black color is the page that has to be "hide" with like a .6 opacity
>   Red is the main box with a background color/image
>   Both the description and the "x" are above the red background

And it should be responsive aswell. Can anyone help me out?

What I've tried out so far:

```css
.modal { 
     display: none; 
     position: absolute;  
     z-index: 998;  
     padding-top: 100px;  
     left: 0; 
     top: 0; 
     width: 100%;  
     height: 100%; 
     overflow: auto;  
     background-color: rgb(0,0,0);  
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);  
   text-align: center; 
 } 

 .modal-content { 
     margin: auto; 
     display: block; 
     min-height: 150px; 

   z-index: 999; 
 } 

 .top{ 
   width:100%; 
   top: 0; 
   text-align: right; 
   direction: rtl; 
   position: absolute; 
   height:15px; 
 } 

 .ico{ 
   width:15px; 
   height: 15px; 
   background-color: blue; 
   position: relative; 
 } 

 #caption { 
   width:90%; 
   background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.7); 
   color: white; 
   padding-left: 16px; 
   text-transform:uppercase; 
   height:50px; 
   margin-top: -50px; 
   z-index: 9999; 
   position: relative; 
 } 

 .modal-content, #caption {     
     -webkit-animation-name: zoom; 
     -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s; 
     animation-name: zoom; 
     animation-duration: 0.6s; 
 } 

 @-webkit-keyframes zoom { 
     from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)}  
     to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)} 
 } 

 @keyframes zoom { 
     from {transform:scale(0)}  
     to {transform:scale(1)} 
 } 

 .close { 
     position: absolute; 
     top: 15px; 
     right: 35px; 
     color: #f1f1f1; 
     font-size: 40px; 
     font-weight: bold; 
     transition: 0.3s; 
 } 

 .close:hover, 
 .close:focus { 
     color: #bbb; 
     text-decoration: none; 
     cursor: pointer; 
 } 

 @media only screen and (max-width: 700px){ 
     .modal-content { 
         width: 100%; 
     } 
 }
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <img class="modal-content" id="modalImage" src="someUrl">
    <div class="top">
      <div class="ico">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="caption">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
```

Edit: Solved on my own. Just used the margin: auto trick. Thank you for downvoting randomly.

Comment: There are plenty of lightbox examples online. If you have a more specific issue, post the code and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Haven't found out anything that is like this example. Also code is here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what you want with jQuery :

```js
    $(".show").on("click", function(){
    $(".mask").addClass("active");
  });

  function closeModal(){
    $(".mask").removeClass("active");
  }

  $(".close, .mask").on("click", function(){
    closeModal();
  });

  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
      closeModal();
    }
  });
```

```css
    .show {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -75px;
    background: black;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 35px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
  }
  .mask {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    z-index: 50;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.7s;
  }
  .modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    margin-top: -150px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 100;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s ease-out;
    transform: translateY(45px);
  }
  .active {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .active + .modal {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="show" aria-haspopup="true">Show</button>

 <div class="mask" role="dialog"></div>
 <div class="modal" role="alert">
  <button class="close" role="button">X</button>
 </div>
```